# Получение MAC-адреса клиента внутри локальной сети

Tags: python, ubuntu, django, debian, wifi

Есть точка доступа с порталом(debian), на django который после авторизации пускает в сеть. Возможно ли средствами django узнать MAC-адрес клиента или это необходимо делать средствами debian?

Comment: *Возможно ли средствами django узнать MAC-адрес клиента* Даже если такая возможность есть, всё одно приложение обратится к ОС за информацией из её ARP-таблицы. Так что есть ли смысл использовать посредника? С другой стороны, связать клиента с его IP для получения затем МАС может только сам клиент.

Comment: Ок, а возможно ли средствами django узнать ip-адрес, чтобы потом связать его с MAC-адресом из ARP таблицы?

Comment: Ну я достаточно быстро нашёл, как - [ссылка](https://evileg.com/ru/post/181/). Истинность проверяйте сами - не спец...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
system ("ip ne | grep 'IP-ADDRESS-OF-THE-CLIENT ' | awk '{print $5}'")
```

Извините, не знаю, как оно на питоне, но главное тут команда.
Обратите внимание на пробел после IP-адреса. Это чтобы при поиске, например, 192.168.1.2 в результат не попали .20, .25, .221 и т.д.

В принципе, должно работать на большинстве линуксов, не только на дебианах.

Answer (score 1):

Средствами Дебиана, прямо в django:

Чекни, как там у вас в пухтоне выполнять системные команды: и когда клиент подключился к сети - **`cat /proc/net/arp`**